# Block device from accessing the Internet, but not Wi-Fi

Tags: airport, internet, mac-address

I have an Apple Airport and I would like to find out how to configure devices that can access the home network but be blocked from accessing the Internet.

I know how to block a device from accessing Wi-Fi completely, but all I want is to limit a device from accessing the Internet. I still want the device to be able to connect to other computers, the file server, the printer, etc. on the local network.

I am hoping for a router-based solution, such as discussed [here.](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080125121305AAwGF6U.)

Is this possible with Airport?

Comment: Could you maybe explain what your final goal is? It could be that people have other solutions for your problem.

Comment: Apologies, I had thought I phrased it clearly, but English is not my first language. I want the Eye-Fi card to still connect to my laptop via wifi, but not be able to connect to the internet.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But *why* do you want to block the internet connection of the Eye-Fi? What do you achieve when you block the internet connection?

Comment: Hi Bart. Specifically for Eye-Fi, I want to make sure it doesn't send pics anywhere else. However, it's a more general question - I want to be able to block a device from accessing the web without being blocked for interacting with other devices at home. For instance, I want to eventually block web access for a laptop for my kid and access pics and files on the home network, but not access the web.

Comment: Ok, this makes it more clear. Could you also add which Eye-Fi card you have? Different versions have different capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent a device from accessing the internet, but allowing it to access files on a local network over Wi-Fi you can setup an ad hoc network.

The ad hoc network will be hosted by your Mac and devices, like your Eye-Fi card* or your kids laptop, can connect to it and access shared local folders.

1. Turn Airport On
   [image]
   [image]
2. Click on `Create a Network`. The following screen will appear:
   [image]
3. If you want password protection, check `Require Password` and type a desired password.
   [image]
4. Hit Ok. Now you're Mac is broadcasting a network.

The [Eye-Fi support page](http://support.eye.fi/cards/networks/ad-hoc-networks-pro-cards-only/connect-card-to-an-ad-hoc-network/) explains how to connect to an ad hoc network.

- Note on the Eye-Fi card: according to [this website](http://support.eye.fi/cards/networks/ad-hoc-networks-pro-cards-only/eye-fi-card-support-ad-hoc-wi-fi/) only the Eye-Fi Pro and Eye-Fi Pro X2 can connect to an ad hoc network.

General note: if you want other devices to access files and folders on your Mac those files and folders have to be shared. How to do that is suitable for another question.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Bart. I appreciate you spending time on my query. I was hoping for a router-based solution, such as discussed at http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080125121305AAwGF6U.  That approach means all devices is still on the same network, and just that some devices are blocked from connecting to the web.  Your suggestion would, for instance, allow my kid's laptop to connect to my macbook, but prevent it from connecting to our file server.

Comment: @undetected Ok, no problem. But please update your question with all these exact details. This will help answerers to give you an answer that is better suited for your question.